# Powerpoint does not play Embedded Audio (voiceover)

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I work for a university. Some faculty distribute their lectures as Powerpoint slideshows with embedded audio. The audio works fine for most students, but a few are having issues. All the students have Powerpoint 2010.

If I extract the audio from the Powerpoint slide (by changing it to a zipfile), the audio clips play just fine on the student's computer. This ensures it is not a problem with the audio being embedded improperly or using a codec they do not have available.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a year later, I found the answer!

The issue is related to execution protection. If you remove the 'fetched from the Internet' attribute from the file then Powerpoint will play the audio.

[image]

Solution: Just click **Unblock** on the bottom of the properties for the PowerPoint file. When you next open it, the audio will play.

Comment: +1 for coming back a year later and giving the answer so people like me who came her on 07/23/2012 (or later) can learn. Bravo Zulu.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird one for sure... :)  If the workstations in question are running Vista or 7, ensure that PowerPoint hasn't been muted/turned down in the audio Mixer (Vista+ allows per-application volume settings in the mixer).

[image: Vista Mixer Button]
[image: Mixer Open]

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I checked. I forgot to mention that it is not app specific volume.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I checked the properties and the file was not blocked. Eventually I discovered that I had to download DivX software to play the audio

Comment: This would be a potential fix, except that the audio plays when extracted from the Zip (and I can see that the WAVs do not contain any unusually encoded audio). It's not a codec issue.